# Fazer um loop com php em uma class HTML

Tags: php, html

Vamos supor que eu tenha uma div dentro de um foreach e dentro dessa div eu tenha uma outra div com uma classe x, porém gostaria que essa classe x fosse numerada a cada repetição, existe essa possibilidade?

Exemplo do código:

```
<?php
                    foreach ($list_menu as $key => $menu):
                    ?>
                            <?php
                            if(count($menu->subMenu)):
                            ?>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="<?= base_url('categoria/' . $menu->txtUrlMenuSite); ?>"><?= strtolower($menu->txtMenu); ?></a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            <ul class="sub-nav">
                                                <?php
                                                foreach ($menu->subMenu as $key => $sub):
                                                ?>
                                                    <li><a href="<?= base_url('categoria/' . $sub->txtUrlMenuSite); ?>"><?= $sub->txtMenu; ?></a></li>
                                                <?php
                                                endforeach;
                                                ?>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            <?php
                            else:
                            ?>
                                <li><a href="<?= base_url('categoria/' . $menu->txtUrlMenuSite); ?>"><?= strtolower($menu->txtMenu); ?></a></li>
                            <?php
                            endif;
                            ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php
                    endforeach;
                    ?>
```

Comment: Você pode colocar uma parte do código para ficar mais clara a pergunta, amigo?

Comment: coloca um count $count = 0;  foreach(sue foreachaqui) {  echo "<div class='x$count'></div>"; $count++;}

Comment: Woton Sampaio, desculpa amigo acabei de editar o post, muito obrigado!

Comment: Marcos Brinner, muito obrigado, irei tentar agora!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gustavo,

você pode fazer:

```
$a = "";
foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
   $a .= "<div><div class='x_".$key."'></div></div>";

 echo $a;
```

ou tbm colocar um contador:

```
$count = 0;
$a = "";
foreach ($arr as $value)
    $a .= "<div><div class='x_".$count++."'></div></div>";

echo $a;
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Gabriel Carvalho, com a sua resposta e a dos outros amigos consegui resolver o problema!!

Comment: @GustavoSiqueira, evite agradecer nos comentários. O agradecimento já é um UpVote, e confirmação da resposta. :]